# INSERT INTO adds leading and trailing spaces

Tags: ms-access, vba

Why does INSERT INTO add leading and trailing spaces to strings in the following:

```
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Rounds] ([Round ID],[Cource ID],[Round Date],[Tee Time],[Handicap Round],[Player ID],[Player HCP],[Slope],[Tee],[Holes Played],[Comments],[Green Fee],[GF Term])" & _
                                    " VALUES (' " & TempVars!tvNewRoundID & " ',' " & TempVars!tvCourceID & " ',' " & TempVars!tvRoundDate & " ',' " & TempVars!tvTeeTime & " ',' " & TempVars!tvHandicapRound & " ',' " & TempVars!tvPlayerID & " ',' " & [Forms]![Data Entry Form]![txtPlayerHCP] & " ',' " & TempVars!tvPlayerSlope & " ',' " & TempVars!tvTeeName & " ',' " & TempVars!tvHolesPlayed & " ',' " & TempVars!tvComments & " ',' " & TempVars!tvGreenFee & " ',' " & TempVars!tvGreenFeeTerm & " ' );"
```

Declarations are like this:
Public tvNewRoundID As TempVars
Public tvRoundDate As TempVars
Public tvTeeName As Variant etc.

The problem applies for strings only, everything else works fine. I have tried by trimming before INSERT INTO with no avail, the spaces appear in the table.

Comment: Because your insert query creates them. Remove the spaces between the single and double quotes.

Comment: I have to add that seems a very strange use of TempVars, what is the source of that data you have stored into tempvars ?

Comment: Thanks Pritaeas, that made the trick, and I thought I had tried that already….
Minty: Your question implies that using tempvars is not very professional  way of doing this, and I appreciate that. The source varies and I tried to make it look nice and neat only.